# The image of the unit disk for $\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{|z_k|}{z_k}\left(\frac{z_k-z}{1-\bar{z_k}z}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the unit disk $|z|\le 1$ for the function

$$f(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{|z_k|}{z_k}\left(\frac{z_k-z}{1-\bar{z_k}z}\right),$$

where $0\lt |z_k|\lt 1$ for every $k$.

[image]

The answer is that the image is the unit disk n times. I found this theorem in the text and so $f$ is a n product of functions of this form. But what does it mean that the image is the unit disk n times? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: It means that every $w \in \Delta$ has exactly $n$ preimages in $\Delta$, counting multiplicity.